# Adding new column (with inner join) and insert (update) value with case when (SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the best approach to add a column to an existing table with values
I've the following tables:

```
Table_A
ClientID, StatementID, CustBuy

Table_B
NewClientID
```

I want to add a new column **YTD_Jan13**

```
alter Table_A add YTD_Jan13 varchar(20)

select 
(case
    when CustBuy=0 and StatementID>='01.01.2013' then 'New YTD'
    else 'Repead YTD'
end) as YTD_Jan13
from A inner join B
on A.ClientID = B.NewClientID
```

Basically I want to insert value in a new column (**YTD_Jan13**) with following conditions:
If
1) Table_A.ClientID = Table_B.NewClientID
2) in a Table_A (CustBuy=0 and StatementID>='01.01.2013') then **'New YTD'**
else **'Repead YTD'**

I'm confused, I'm asking for your help
Thanks in advance
BR, Habib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alter Table_A add YTD_Jan13 varchar(20)
```

Then stick your 'else' value in

```
update Table_A Set YTD_Jan13 = 'Repeat YTD'
```

then (this is called an update with join)

```
UPDATE  a
  SET   a.YTD_Jan13 = 'New YTD'
FROM    Table_A a 
INNER JOIN B 
ON A.ClientID = B.ClientID
Where CustBuy = 0 and StatementID >= '01.01.2013'
```

NB There is an assumption that there are no records for clients in A that are not in B. If there are you'll have to get a bit cleverer so YTD_Jan13 would be left null in those cases.